# How to get data from webservice method an android using Soap Method

Tags: android

```
[WebMethod]
public string Grade()
{

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = ConnectionClass.Selectcommand("select ProductName,PurchasePrice from Product");
    resultC res = new resultC { result = dt };
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res);
    return json;

}
```

How to get data from the above webservice method an android using Soap Method
please, help me

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [ksoap](http://simpligility.github.io/ksoap2-android/index.html) for this.

Comment: please, give me the solution

Comment: You can search for tutorials on ksoap.

Comment: Can you tell me, my webservice is ok or not. return data of this service is <string>[{"ProductName":"BD-1","PurchasePrice":165.00}]</string> how to handle this data android